# What is this red mark on my dog’s forehead?

Tags: dogs, health

I was doing a little bit of a checkup on our family dog, Rocky, and I found a strange small bump on top of his forehead, in between his ears. I was a bit concerned, so I began looking online, to check whether this was a zit. While I was examining the area, Rocky seemed uncomfortable, so I stopped touching around there. After some online research I’m still not certain what this bump is. Rocky is a 10 month old bull mastiff puppy. Here’s a picture of the mark I found:

[image: Red Bump]

**Does anyone have any idea what this could be?**

Comment: where do you live,it is an insect bite but what type depends on where you live and the type of nature you have.

Comment: @trondhansen We live in a forest. We haven’t had many issues with ticks, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a tick bite. Ticks are most common in coastal or in lowland areas, but as a direct result of increasing global warming, the areas where ticks can live are expanding.

If you live in an area where roedeer-deer-moose-elk are common, you will most likely find ticks.

More information about ticks could be found [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick).

Another type of similar bitemark comes from the deer fly; a bite from this insect can often take from a month and up to a year before it heals completely.

As the name says, deer fly is spread by animals in the deer family and the living area for the deer fly has been expanding during the last years (here in Scandinavia).

More information about deer flies could be found [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipoptena_cervi).

Both ticks and deer flies can spread disease to people and pets, so please keep your own and your pets' vaccinations up to date.

Comment: Ok, I believe it might be a horse/deer fly, because we just opened the pool and that's when they really start attacking things.

Comment: @OKprogrammer it sounds likely,i have a garden pond and deer fly are living there,i have been bitten several times.